# Can I contact graduate office regarding decision timeline (to know my application status)?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school

I am an applicant of Graduate program in Biological sciences of X University, USA. My application deadline was Dec 15, 2015 and I submitted application with required documents on time (PhD application). For the past 4 months my application status in portal shows "In review". In the university website,no specific decision timeline is given. My question is can I contact through e-mail to graduate program coordinator to know the decision status? It is almost April 1st week, I fear my application might be rejected, but I want to know it from officials.

Is it normal to ask Graduate program coordinator to ask about decision timeline or my application status?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You will likely find out within the next few weeks. But asking them the date by which they'll let applicants know their decision status is a perfectly reasonable question. After all, you might have other offers that may require a time-sensitive answer.

I don't know if I'd ask *directly* about your application status, but asking for their review timeline is perfectly reasonable and appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. However, if I remember correctly, I believe schools need to send you the decision by April 10-15th. That was the case from me when I applied (to engineering in 2011).

Comment: I don't think this is the case for every graduate program. I know of a US school who has a program where the deadline for the fall semester is in May for a Masters without financial aid.

Comment: I agree. Different schools have different deadlines. I was stating my experience and assumed that the OP was an international students like me.

Answer (score 0):

I would check your program's website before contacting your advisor. It may contact information on when decisions will be announced. You just don't want to reach out to them if it's clearly known that the decisions aren't ready.

If there is information on this on the website that indicates you should have heard by now, I would definitely reach out and ask for an update.